# Find File based on partial file name and move file elsewhere in vbs

Tags: file, parsing, scripting, vbscript

I'm looking to write a vbs script to do the following.
- There is a mapping file which contains an identifier followed by a directory name (e.g. 123456-Documents).
- For each line in the mapping file, there will be a document which begins with the identifier that I need to move elsewhere (e.g. 123456_otherStuff_Dec 12.xls).
- I then need to parse the full filename and take the middle string (otherStuff) to determine which sub directory it goes into.

So in the above example, the file "123456_otherStuff_Dec 12.xls" should end up in the directory C:.../current/Documents/otherStuff/123456_otherStuff_Dec 12.xls.

I'm new to vbs, but I know a bit of Java so have been able to make a start on this. This is what I have so far:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Documents and Settings\w133960\Desktop\test1\Text1.txt", ForReading) 

Const ForReading = 1 

Dim arrFileLines() 
i = 0 
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream 
Redim Preserve arrFileLines(i) 
arrFileLines(i) = objFile.ReadLine 
i = i + 1 
Loop 
objFile.Close 


For Each strLine in arrFileLines 
WScript.Echo strLine 
MyArray = Split(strLine, "-", -1, 1)
WScript.Echo MyArray(0)
WScript.Echo MyArray(1)

Next
```

This goes through the mapping file and will parse the identifer for me. The next part would be searching for the file beginning with the identifier, then parse it's filename and move it into the relevant directory based on that.
I could add another For Loop inside the current loop, then parse the filename and move the file within that loop - but I am worried about the efficieny of this as there are a few hundred files to move.
Can anyone advise on the cleanest and most efficient way of doing this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where are the files located? Are they all in one folder or do you need to search the entire filesystem? Is the ID unique or could there be several file names starting with the same ID? Are all destination folders relative to the same parent directory?

Comment: Files are all in the one folder. There may be several filenames with the same starting ID, but the files would be moved into different directories based on the rest of the filename. All destination folders are relative to the same parent directory.

Comment: Then go with what @Ekkehard.Horner suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plan:

1. A first loop to extract the Ids (and the folder names) from the
   mapping file into a `dictionary` (key = id, value = folder name
   (possibly)) [never duplicate the lines collection in a file into an
   array in memory, if you don't need to access item i to process item
   j (i <>j)]
2. A second loop over the files in the (one and only?) source directory. `Split` the oFile.`Name` on the correct! separator "_", not "-". If the Id is found in the dictionary, use the parts to build (`FileSystemObject.BuildPath()`) the new/target file spec. Check (`FileSystemObject.FileExists()`) whether the targext exists, if not, oFile.`Move`